# WCF Exception occured after Server is configured to support TLS 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service which is created using ASP.NET 4.5. I am consuming this service from an ASP.NET 1.1 WebForm application.Everything was working fine until the Server in which the WCF service is hosted in IIS was configured to support only TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 and disabled the support for TLS 1.0/SSL V3.

Now, each time the ASP.NET 1.1 Web App tries to consume the WCF service, this below exception is being thrown.

[System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS.]

I searched the web and found that upgrading the framework to 4.5 or setting the security protocol as `[ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12]` will solve this problem.

I can't upgrade the legacy 1.1 to 4.5 but can use the second protocol setting.But, the code `[ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12]` will not work in the versions below ASP.NET 3.5.

I need some suggestions for how to set this protocol as the current legacy application which is built in ASP.NET 1.1 can't be upgraded to ASP.NET 4.5, where the TLS 1.2 is supported by default.

Thanks in advance :)